# Removing a node from a tree causes it to become a disjoint union of disjoint paths

Tags: graph-theory

**Question:**
Let T be a Tree of exactly $k\ge2$ leafs. $v\in V(T)$ is a vertex s.t $deg(v)\ge k$. Prove that $T-v$ is a disjoint union of $k$ non empty disjoint paths.

**My solution:**

- Induction Base: if k=2 then if we delete a vertex of such, it must not be a leaf, so we are left with 2 leafs with no edges at all, and this fulfills the conditions.
- Induction Step: we assume by contradiction that after a removal of such vertex $v$ then the remainder is a union of paths which are not disjoint. This implies existence of an edge $e=(u,x)$ which takes part of 2 paths $P_1, P_2$. We'll prove that in such case the original $T$ is not a tree as it has a cycle. 
  Denote the leafs of $T: l_1...l_k$. WLOG we can say that $P_1, P_2$ are two paths from $l_1, l_2 \rightarrow v$. These exists because of v's degree. 
  We can create a cycle starting from v, travelling on $vP_1 x P_2v$ (we may travel on only a part of those 2 paths). This is a contradiction to T being a tree, so the statement is proven.

I would like to verify correctness for this proof, as I still feel something is missing. Especially on a more percise explanation on why such paths must exist from the leafs to v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument there is not really an induction proof, but it does seem to address parts of the requirement.

In answer to one question from you: since $T$ is a tree, there is a path from any node to any other node.

I would also observe that the degree of $v$ must be exactly $k$; it cannot be greater than $k$ or there would be two paths from $v$ to at least one of the leaf nodes, forming a cycle. And with the degree of $v$ being $k$, by a similar pigeonhole-type argument, each edge from $v$ must lead to exactly one leaf, because if one edge connected out to $2$ leaves there would be one of the remaining $k-2$ leaves somewhere that was connected to $2$ of the remaining $k-1$ edges from $v$.

Combining these ideas with your cycle-proving argument should complete the proof.